# DB2 RECORDSET table name converted to uppercase

Tags: db2

"SQL0204N  "FUSIONDBUNIT.ACQUIREDRUN" is an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704

The table is actually AcquireRun and not ACQUIREDRUN

Following line throws the exception

pRecordSet->Open(CRecordset::dynaset, NULL,CRecordset::readOnly | CRecordset::skipDeletedRecords)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: AcquireRun vs ACQUIREDRUN. I see that the actual table does not have a "D" in the name, but the table in the error message does. Is there a typo in your code?

Answer (score 3):

DB2 table names are not case-sensitive **unless** you define them with double-quotes around the name, e.g. `CREATE TABLE "MySchema"."MyTable" (...)` will only work if you do:

```
SELECT *
FROM "MySchema"."MyTable"
```

I won't work even if you do `SELECT * FROM MySchema.MyTable` because DB2 automatically folds identifiers to upper-case, unless you quote them.

However, as noted by @sl0ppy, it looks like you might have a typo, `AcquireRun` vs. `ACQUIREDRUN` (no `D`).